# Deploying to iOS device from Unreal fails

Tags: ios, metal, unreal-engine4

I'm attempting to build and deploy an Unreal project to an iPhone, but it's failing to deploy on two errors. Xcode v11.3.1, Unreal v4.22.

LogShaderCompilers: Error:    /tmp/3689_966125236.metal(0): Xcode's metal shader compiler was not found, verify Xcode has been installed on this Mac and that it has been selected in Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command-line Tools.
  LogOutputDevice: Warning: Script Stack (0 frames):

LogMac: Error: appError called: Assertion failed:  [File:/Users/build/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 4523]
  Failed to compile global shader TSlateElementPSFonttruetrueA  .  Enable 'r.ShaderDevelopmentMode' in ConsoleVariables.ini for retries.

and

[DD]  ... Error: Failed to connect to bundle 'com.dock10.FACE'

So far I've:

- Verified the metal compiler location using xcrun -sdk macosx -find metal
- Verified Xcode has been installed and that it has been selected in Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command-line Tools.
- Successfully packaged and deployed a simple swift project to the iPhone through xcode
- Tried pretty much every suggestion I can find on Google
- Delete Binaries, Build, Intermediate, Saved folders in project folder, then Generate Xcode project
- Entered r.ShaderDevelopmentMode into UE4 commandline

I don't have an apple dev license, do I need one to build and deploy my unreal project to one local iPhone?

Thanks!

Comment: Well UE4 is bound to it's Xcodes unfortunately, to deploy from 4.22 you will need an Xcode version that 4.22 was built on. Or you can try to migrate your project to 4.24.

Comment: if you could build a simple swift project and run it on iPhone seems like you don't need an Apple developer license for that ?

Comment: So installing XCode 10.1, as mentioned in the iOS Development Requirements for 4.22 seems to have fixed the shader error, great! That Failed to connect to bundle error is still present though and I'd like clarification whether I need to buy an Apple dev license to get provisioning and certificates or not.

Comment: I don’t know, you may want to ask a separate question on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So installing XCode 10.1, as mentioned in the iOS Development Requirements for 4.22 seems to have fixed the shader error, great!